# How to render link label over the node and its label in Zoomchart netchart

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts, netchart

I am creating Netchart using Zoomchart library. When I hover the link, link label is showing but behind the Node and its label, but I want link label should show at the top whenever I hover the link. [image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Rendering sequence is:
1) links
2) link labels & link items
3) nodes
4) node items

You can improve the layout using rotateWithLink setting:

https://jsfiddle.net/jhaqtrgs/

```
    style:{
        node:{imageCropping: true},
        nodeStyleFunction: nodeStyle,
        linkLabel: {
            rotateWithLink: true
        },
        linkStyleFunction: function(link){
            link.label = link.id;
        },
        linkMinZoom: 0,
        linkMinSize: 0
    }
```

J.